# Check if name exists php

Tags: php, rest, api

I have an api which posts gathered data from my form on my website.
The data is gathered with an array like this:

```
$org_payload = array(
        'name' => $_POST['billing_company'],
        'phone' => $_POST['billing_phone'],
        'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
        'note' =>$_POST['order_comments'],
        'relation_type' => array(
            'id'=>'relationtype:c1ec3ae77036842d' //provide the relationtypeid, f.e. relationtype:796ce0d318a2f5db515efc18bba82b90
        ),
        'visiting_address' => array(
            'country_code'          =>  'NL',
             'line_1'               =>  $_POST['billing_address_1'],
             'postal_code'          =>  $_POST['billing_postcode'],
             'locality'             =>  $_POST['billing_city'],
             'country'              =>  $_POST['billing_country']

        ), // can be extented with other address data
        'postal_address' => array(
            'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ) // can be extented with other address data
);
```

Then it gets sent like this:

```
$organization = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/organization',json_encode($org_payload));
```

I want that when the array item name already exists to make it echo something.

All the newly entered data gets stored in a json format in this url:

> /api/v2/crm/organization

The get request looks like this:

```
$test = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('GET','/api/v2/crm/organization?q');
```

Here is an example of what i want in pseudo code:

```
if(name already exists){
     echo 'this name already exists'
 } else {
//Post it
$organization = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/organization',json_encode($org_payload));
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/array_key_exists) function

```
if (array_key_exists('name', $org_payload)) {
   // do something
   echo 'this name already exists'
} else {
   // make API call
}
```

the other option are [isset()](http://php.net/isset) which also check if variable is not null(is set) and [empty()](http://php.net/empty) which checks whether variable exists is not null and is not empty.

Comment: I wanted to check if the array key name existed inside mydomain.com/api/v2/crm/organization.json

Comment: so json_decode() it to php array and check it via array_key_exists